Using Google's generative AI for images in Kotlin
I'm trying to use Google's generative AI in Kotlin in Android Studio, to write an app that gives me information about a photo.
So I would like to pass an image and a text to the gemini-1.5-flash API, but I am not succeeding.
This is my code:
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val prompt = arrayOf(
        Content.Image(selectedImageBitmap),
        "What is in this photo?")
    val response = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        generativeModel.generateContent(prompt)
    }
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        OutputValue = response.text
        myTextOutput.text = OutputValue
    }
}

selectedImageBitmap is a bitmap object.
In build.grandle.kts file, I've added the dependencies:
implementation("com.google.ai.client.generativeai:generativeai:0.9.0")


And in my MainActivity, I've added the import:
import com.google.ai.client.generativeai.GenerativeModel

I have the following error:

Unresolved reference: Content.

That means, the compiler cannot find the definition of 'Content.
What's wrong with my code?
What do I need to do to get it to work?
I expected generativeModel.generateContent() to easily accept text, images, PDFs, and other input types.
